# How to queue and update a dataGridView with 2 buttons in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, button, datagridview

I have 2 different buttons a couple of textBoxes and a dataGridView.

The first button is used to insert the data and put it into the textBoxes and it does that. But I want it to somehow queue the data and not immediately put it in dataGridView.

The second button would the be a update button that would put all the data that I have queued up into dataGridView

Comment: what about putting the data in a global variable?

Answer (score 0):

Not a lot of information here, but from what I'm gathering, you could create a custom Class that holds the information from the Textboxs:

```
public Class myTextBoxClass
{
       private string TextBox1 { get; set; }
       private string TextBox2 { get; set; }
}
```

Inside your form, create a global List of your custom class...

```
private List<myTextBoxClass> textBoxClassList = new List<myTextBoxClass>();
```

On your first button click, create a new class and add that class to your global List.

```
myTextBoxClass singleEntry = new myTextBoxClass
{
     TextBox1 = textbox1.Text,
     TextBox2 = textbox2.Text
};
textBoxClassList.Add(singleEntry);
```

Then your second button would do the adding of your List items to the DataGridView

```
foreach(myTextBoxClass entry in TextBoxClassList)
{
     this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(entry.TextBox1, entry.TextBox2);
}
```